# What would be an ideal data structure to represent an image matrix?

Tags: c++, performance, image-processing, data-structures, memory-efficient

As I'm doing a computer vision library, I wondered what would be the ideal data structure to save an image's data.

Someone told me that doing an std::vector imbrication is pretty bad since data contiguity isn't guaranteed, thus a simple one is more efficient.

Problem is, the vector's content has to be colorspace-dependant. Plus, for size issues it would be best to have an unsigned char per channel, though I'd be better off having floats to perform operations.

To handle colorspaces, should I increase the size of the vector (like tripling it to handle RGB), so I could access data like this:

```
data[0] => pixel 1, Red
data[1] => pixel 1, Green
data[2] => pixel 1, Blue
data[3] => pixel 2, Red
data[4] => pixel 2, Green
... etc
```

Or is it possible to do this more efficiently (like using a long int or a float to keep all channel's values into one single variable) and if so, how? How could I make this generic to handle 1, 2, 3 or 4 channels so that I can change colorspace (relatively) easily?

**The question is not about the container (I am using a single std::vector already), but the content itself.**

**EDIT**: Since this question has been marked as primarily opinion-based, I will try to make it clearer.

At the moment, I'm storing an image's data in a `std::vector<float>`. The problem here is that I don't know how many items to store (e.g. 3 times the size to handle RGB/HSV, or implementing a 4-items struct (RGBA) even when I'm only using one (grayscale)?) in order to efficiently change colorspace or perform operations on matrices when I need to. As this is meant to be integrated in a computer vision library, it is **highly likely** to happen at least once every frame.

*I'm asking for something **efficient** in my case here, which has nothing (or very little) to do with opinion. There could be several good answers and chosing among them relies on opinion, but this is supposed to be my call.*

Comment: `std::vector` guarantees that data is stored contiguously in memory.

Comment: what is "best"? There are many ways and they all have their advantages and disadvantages. I suggest you just check out various opensource image processing libraries and see how they do it. you also might want to ask yourself if it makes sense to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @JesperJuhl For one vector indeed, not thousands. In a 3000x3000 pixels' image, there would be 3001 vectors and not all of them would be contiguously stored.

Comment: @Piglet By this I meant "most efficient". I intend to optimize this as much as I can, since this is the core of a computer vision library I'd rather not have memory/speed issues there.

Comment: Why not just use one vector with 9.000.000 elements?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing (sorry if it was unclear), the question was actually about how to store this single vector, and particularly which type it should handle :)

Comment: Interleaved formats are annoying to process, so if there is no particular reason for the interleaving I would avoid it.

Comment: you can use `vector v` of `struct rgba` . In order to access red component of `pixel[x][y]` use `v[x*total_rows+y].red`. Although you will waste 1 byte for rgb images. Else create separate class for rgb image in which there is `vector<unsigned char>` and store the data as shown in you post. Also write conversion functions to convert one type to another.

Comment: Also, note just using single vector for image is not a good idea, because image come with height, width, pixelformat. So its better to abstract it using classes.

Comment: @sameerkn I am using a class, which contains width, height and the vector of data, so no problem on that part. I thought about always using 4 channels, but I'm going to handle grayscale so 3 will be useless, case which I'd want to avoid. I could create one class per colorspace, but I'd rather have a colorspace-agnostic matrix class if I can (just like OpenCV does). Using only `unsigned char` seems indeed like a good solution, but there's still the problem of matrix operations (way not enough precision on chars).

Comment: You can always have `vector<unsigned char>` and have helper `member_functions` inside your class which can get and set a pixel (of type rgb, rgba, grayscale). Some normal calculations are required to access appropriate pixel or appropriate component(r, g, b, a) of appropriate pixel.

Comment: If someone could explain how is my question opinion-based (I've edited it to try to make it clearer) OR remove the "on hold" if what I added is enough, that would be great.

Comment: The problem is that images are a lot like passwords, all the space you save by compressing them limits the space itself, and increases computation needed to recover the final raw pixel data to be drawn on screen. The best you can do is choose one of infinitely many ways to encode such raw pixel data or mix and match them/make your own, but in the end you will always just be trading between time to decode and space to store. The best representation in terms of space is just a link or image identifier number possibly guid, best in terms of computation is a raw bitmap.

Comment: actually on second thought, a bitmap might be slower than some graphics api specific format that draws everything in terms of triangles rather than pixels, but i'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the "best" data structure for an image data highly depends on what kind of operations you want to perform on the image, and mostly on what operations you want to have optimized performances.

Usually a `std::vector` of bytes can be enough (for the whole image, not a vector for each single line); a vector guarantees that data is stored in a contiguous block of memory, which may or may not fit your use cases (i.e. it doesn't if you need to manage strides longer than scanlines).

If you need more fine-grained access to the pixelformat information (i.e. single color components), you may want to use a custom defined structure for pixel representation.

Also, data structure may be more complex depending on which kind of images you need to manage. 
I.e. are you limited to 1 or a few pixelformats?
Are you limited to "packed" images (sequential color components in 1 "plane") or do you need to manage also "planar" images (multiple "planes", one for each color component)?

You may also look at some available graphics libraries on the web.
One that (in my opinion) has an interesting pixel components management (with custom iterators and other facilities) is [Boost GIL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html)

Comment: Good answer. [This](http://homepages.e3.net.nz/~djm/containerchoice.png) is a good starting point.

Comment: The question may actually be unclear, I shouldn't have asked about "data structure" literally, but its content. I always consider the picture @erip provided when I have doubts about what to use, though here I'm pretty sure there would be no better alternative (std::array would not be good since the size is clearly not known at compile time, and I highly doubt the other ones would be convenient to store pixels which have to be accessed and modified anytime). A structure would be great, but as I've asked there's the problem of changing colorspace, that's precisely the problem!

Comment: Upvoted for providing GIL's link. I absolutely didn't know about this, I'll read it in detail, thanks!